# ng-click with a dynamic {{}} string

Tags: angularjs

I have a HTML `table` that has the `id` set with a databind inside of a *ng-repeat*

```
<div class="project" ng-repeat="project in data.projects">
    <h2>
      {{projectState.name}}
    </h2>
    <table class="table" id="{{project.name + selectedType}}">
    ...
    </table>
    ...
</div>
```

This properly sets the `id` as expected, but I need to use this `id` in a *ng-click* call.

```
<button ng-click="export({{project.name + selectedType}})">
...
</button>
```

This produces the error when the page loads

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 16 of the expression [export({{project.name + selectedType}})] starting at [{project.name + selectedType}})].
```

How do I properly reference the databound `id` of `{{project.name + selectedType}}` in a *ng-click*?

Comment: this button is inside your table right ?

Comment: it's inside the `div`

Comment: ng-click expects an angular expression. The mustaches shouldn't be there: `ng-click="export(project.name + selectedType)"`

Comment: Are you trying to pass a reference to the element into the export() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `project.name` and `selectedType` as 2 arguments to `export` method :

```
<button ng-click="export(project.name,selectedType)">
...
</button>
```

and inside `export` method concatenate them:

```
$scope.export = function(name, type){
   var val = name + type;
   // ...
}
```

---

or just remove `{{` `}}` from `export`

Comment: That did it with `export(project.name + selectedType)` but I like your method more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give an expression inside of `export()`. This should be resolved using

```
export(project.name,selectedType)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtlrl',function($scope){
$scope.projects=[
  { id: 1, name: 'John', address: 'Highway 71'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Peter', address: 'Lowstreet 4'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Amy', address: 'Apple st 652'},
  { id: 4, name: 'Hannah', address: 'Mountain 21'},
  { id: 5, name: 'Michael', address: 'Valley 345'},
  { id: 6, name: 'Sandy', address: 'Ocean blvd 2'},
  { id: 7, name: 'Betty', address: 'Green Grass 1'},
  { id: 8, name: 'Richard', address: 'Sky st 331'},
  { id: 9, name: 'Susan', address: 'One way 98'},
  { id: 10, name: 'Vicky', address: 'Yellow Garden 2'},
  { id: 11, name: 'Ben', address: 'Park Lane 38'},
  { id: 12, name: 'William', address: 'Central st 954'},
  { id: 13, name: 'Chuck', address: 'Main Road 989'},
  { id: 14, name: 'Viola', address: 'Sideway 1633'}
];

$scope.export=function(id){
alert(id);
};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtlrl">
  <div class="project">
      <table class="table" id="{{project.name + address}}" border=1>
      <tr><th>ExportButton</th><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
           <td><button ng-click="export(project.name+project.address)">Export</button></td>
           <td>{{project.id}}</td>
           <td>{{project.name}}</td>
           <td>{{project.address}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ng-click, it means you are already in angular scope so you don't need to use {{}} to call a function or evaluate the expression